# Iteration in VBA until a target value is reached

Tags: vba, excel

On the following link there's an Excel file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/undic11wsq88dej/VBA%20Iteration.xlsm?dl=0

In this Excel file you see a calculation in which I want to include an iteration. The value in Cell B5 should be changing by random values until the value in Cell D22 is exactly the same value as in cell B13/D23.

So far I have programmed the following code to get this iteration done:

```
Sub test()
Do Until Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("D22") = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("D23")
Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("B5") = Int((500 - (-500) + 1) * Rnd + (-500)) / 100
Loop
End Sub
```

However, the issue is that the code inserts random values in cell B5
but it is not smart enough to see if those values bring him closer to the
value in Cell B13/D23. Instead it loops through it without ending.

Do you guys have any idea how I can make this iteration smart enough
so it notices if it gets closer to the value in Cell D23 or not.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using solver add in, this tool uses an Algorithm to choose the "random values" so that it can reach a solution quickly

[You can see an example on how to use solver here](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/solver.html)

Comment: Hi Ashtonic, the solver helped me to solve my issue. Thanks for the hint.